# The wireframe view does not show the model

Tags: three.js

I'm using the object-loader to load a basic cube (geometry), and I wanted to get a wireframe view.

It doesn't appear!

When I use (otherGeometry) - from a three.js primitive, it renders it fine with this code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/90/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

var geometry = objLoader.parse(testObj);
var otherGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 5);

var geo = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(geometry);
var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 1});
var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(geo, mat);
scene.add(wireframe);

var testObj = `# cube.obj
#
g cube

v  0.0  0.0  0.0
v  0.0  0.0  1.0
v  0.0  1.0  0.0
v  0.0  1.0  1.0
v  1.0  0.0  0.0
v  1.0  0.0  1.0
v  1.0  1.0  0.0
v  1.0  1.0  1.0

vn  0.0  0.0  1.0
vn  0.0  0.0 -1.0
vn  0.0  1.0  0.0
vn  0.0 -1.0  0.0
vn  1.0  0.0  0.0
vn -1.0  0.0  0.0

f  1//2  7//2  5//2
f  1//2  3//2  7//2 
f  1//6  4//6  3//6 
f  1//6  2//6  4//6 
f  3//3  8//3  7//3 
f  3//3  4//3  8//3 
f  5//5  7//5  8//5 
f  5//5  8//5  6//5 
f  1//4  5//4  6//4 
f  1//4  6//4  2//4 
f  2//1  6//1  8//1 
f  2//1  8//1  4//1`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OBJLoader.parse()` does not return a geometry but an instance of `THREE.Group`. In your particular case, you have to select the geometry of the first child.

```
var group = objLoader.parse( testObj )
var geometry = group.children[ 0 ].geometry;
```

Ta-da! A wonderful wireframe appears (｡◕‿‿◕｡)

Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/9671/

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ooops! Sorry - it's the "tick"!I was looking for a button at the end of your answer -